# Ya no puedo hacer checkout con stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe

Tengo una aplicacion muy sencilla que me hacia un checkout de prueba con stripe, 
pero ahora no me funciona.

al darle al boton de **Hacer Pago**, simplemente no hace nada.

Aqui dejo el codigo respecivo:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'stripe',      '~> 5.1'
```

**app/views/layout/application.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js' %>
```

**app/config/environment/development.erb**

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:development][:secret_key]
```

**app/views/suscripcion/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Hacer Pago", agregar_pago_path, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

**app/views/suscripcion/nueva_tarjeta.js.erb**

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    //key: '<%= Rails.application.credentials.stripe[Rails.env.to_sym][:publishable_key] %>',
    key: '<%= @clave %>',
    //get a publishable key that we put in editor depending on environment: production or development
    locale: 'auto',
    //handle translation
    name: "Prueba de Rafael",
    description: "Información sobre su Pago",
    email: "<%= current_user.email %>",
    panelLabel: "<%= number_to_currency(@monto) %>",
    allowRememberMe: false,
    token: function (token) {
        var form = document.getElementById('suscribiendo-nuevo-pago');
        //we will create element with this id in the next step
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        //creating an <input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="<id>"/>. We will need this information in the next steps to link a user to his card 
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        //adding this input when we use a form.
        form.submit();
    }
});

handler.open();

window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
});
```

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con stripe, pero si antes te funcionaba, podrías probar a volver en tu control de versiones al momento en el cual te funcionaba y ver que cambios has hecho desde entonces. Si no resulta, puede que sea algo en la config. de tu cuenta de stripe que haya cambiado?. Solo ideas

Comment: Ese es el punto, en mi codigo con el cliente no me camina, tenia una prueba que hice y me funciono para octubre del anno pasado, la tenia guardda, solo la ejecute y da el mismo error (no hace nada), justo estaba sospechando algo de eso, voy a revisar mi cuenta stripe, gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Tenias razon estimado Lagos, tenia como la clave suspendida o congelada o no se que, al entrar en mi cuenta, no vi nada, despues de eso, volvi a ejecutar el programa base de stripe y corrio y el de la app del cliente igualmente corrio.

Comment: Me alegro que hayas resuelto. También me ha pasado que uno crea una cuenta trial para desarrollar, pasa el tiempo y al volver ya no funciona porque el periodo de trial expiró.